# Topology: Thinking of the discrete topology on 2 = {0, 1}. Need to show that there is countable subset A of 2^ω...

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the set $2 = \{0, 1\}$ with the discrete topology, i.e. $T = \{\emptyset, 2, \{0\}, \{1\}\}$. Consider the set $2^\omega$. Show that there is a countable subset $A$ of $2^\omega$ whose closure in the product topology is equal to $2^\omega$. Is there such a set if we consider the box topology? Where $\omega = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

I tried following the definitions and follow a straight path, but I could not arrive to the countable subset described. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. (I just need to be pointed in the right direction)

Comment: Hint: the closure of $A$ is the whole space if and only if $A$ intersects every nonempty open set. What are the open sets in the product topology?

Comment: It's difficult to give you a hint without revealing one of these sets. Maybe this might help: a basic neighbourhood of a point $x \in 2^\omega$ (i.e. $x$ is a binary sequence) will be the set of sequences $y \in 2^\omega$ that agree with $x$ on some finite set of indices. For example, an example of a basic neighbourhood of $x = (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots)$ would be $\{y \in 2^\omega : y_0 = y_4 = 0, y_{13} = 1\}$. A dense set needs to contain enough sequences to be able to match any sequence in any finite set of places.

Comment: You've clearly put some effort into solving the problem, but you should try to describe exactly how you went about solving it. This way, users might be able to help you figure out if your original approach could have been fruitful if taken further, if you made some mistake that hindered your original approach, or if you require completely new methods to complete the proof.